# echo or include multiple xml files in php page

Tags: php, xml

I wish to create a list of XML files in a php file.

I need all my xml files to be included in my php file. I have this working see below.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo file_get_contents("exam1.xml");
```

when I try this it works well, now I try more than one.

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo file_get_contents("exam1.xml");
echo file_get_contents("exam2.xml");
```

it dose not read any of the files.

Comment: maybe u need to to save them in variables `$var1 = file_get_contents("exam1.xml"); $var2=file_get_contents("exam2.xml");` than echo variables. also check var_dump()

Comment: Are you trying to make these files download to the browser so the user can save them or are you trying to render the contents on a page?

Comment: @devpro that's a good idea. ill try that now +`1

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok, so i have a button onlick that shows my php page and with some js it renders some elements on a html page

Comment: So you are trying to get these xml files using AJAX? Right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try passing these files back in a JSON object.

Create an array of files and then `json_encode()` that array.

```
<?php
    $f1 = file_get_contents("exam1.xml");
    $f2 = file_get_contents("exam2.xml");

    $response = array('files' => array($f1, $f2));
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Now you will have a simple json object that you can process in the javascript and place 1 or many xml file(s) whereever you want to on the page using straight forward javascript